# Overlay xticklabel and yticklabel in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks

In the picture below I want to overlay the `xticklabel` `$a$` and `yticklabel` `$f(a)$` in `beamer`. Is it possible to overlay ticks labels?

If it's not possible, I can place de labels as nodes, but in that case, what are the defalult position of `xticklabes` and `yticklabes` in `pgfplots`?
Thanks.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    xtick={1},
    xticklabels={$a$},
    ytick={1},
    yticklabels={$f(a)$}, 
    ]
    \addplot+[domain=0:1.5, mark=none, smooth] {x^2} node[anchor=south] {$f(x)$};
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \fill (A) circle (1.2pt);
    \draw[gray, dotted] (A) -- (A|-O);
    \draw[gray, dotted] (A) -- (A-|O);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'overlaying ticks'? Because those ticks, `a` and `f(a)`are not on the same position, and overlaying things usually requires that such things are on the same place.

Comment: I mean to cover and uncover the labels of ticks with \only, \uncover or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plot has two problems at the moment:

- Clipping cuts away the name of the function, `f(x)` (and would cut away any nodes that you place outside). To avoid this, add `clip=false` to the options of the `axis` environment.
- The `coordinate`s are currently defined in `tikzpicture` dimensions, not in the coordinate system of the `axis` environment. Replace `(0,0)` by `(axis cs:0,0)` and `(1,1)` by `(axis cs:1,1)`. Then your gray dotted lines will appear.

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to have the labels appear gradually frame by frame. I don't think that `pgfplots` is able to cooperate with `beamer` directly, so you will need `\node` and `\only` commands.

The plot will have different size in different frames, so it will jump. Therefore we have to set the bounding box explicitly to make it contain the plot in all frames.

The following output is generated from the code below.

> [image][image][image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Has anyone ever used these to navigate?
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    xtick={1},
    xticklabels={},
    ytick={1},
    yticklabels={},
    clip=false
    ]
    \addplot+[domain=0:1.5, mark=none, smooth] {x^2} node[anchor=south] {$f(x)$};
    \coordinate (O) at (axis cs:0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:1,1);
    \fill (A) circle (1.2pt);
    \draw[gray, dotted] (A) -- (A|-O);
    \draw[gray, dotted] (A) -- (A-|O);
    \only<2->{\draw (axis cs:1,-0.03) node[below]{$a$};}
    \only<3->{\draw (axis cs:-0.0164,1) node[left]{$f(a)$};}
  \end{axis}
  \useasboundingbox (-1,-1) rectangle (current axis.above north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Here is another solution that relies on `pgfplots` to position the labels. It is probably a better solution than the one above as long as it is possible to parametrize the plot by macros. It still needs `\useasboundingbox` to avoid that the plot jumps.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Has anyone ever used these to navigate?
\begin{document}
\newcommand\xlabel{} % Check whether definable and initialize
\newcommand\ylabel{} % Check whether definable and initialize
\begin{frame}
\only<2->{\renewcommand\xlabel{$a$}}
\only<3->{\renewcommand\ylabel{$f(a)$}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    xtick={1},
    xticklabels={\xlabel},
    ytick={1},
    yticklabels={\ylabel},
    clip=false
    ]
    \addplot+[domain=0:1.5, mark=none, smooth] {x^2} node[anchor=south] {$f(x)$};
    \coordinate (O) at (axis cs:0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:1,1);
    \fill (A) circle (1.2pt);
    \draw[gray, dotted] (A) -- (A|-O);
    \draw[gray, dotted] (A) -- (A-|O);
  \end{axis}
  \useasboundingbox (-1.3,-1) rectangle (current axis.above north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @gernot for your answer!
I thought that it wasn't possible in pgfplots and for that reason I proposed to use a node as you propose in your answer. But the problem here is that if you add `xticklabels={$a$}` and `yticklabels={$f(a)$}` to the axis definition, you will see that the tick labels doesn't match exactly the labels of your nodes. That's the reason I asked for the default positon of tick labels in pgfplots. Do you know how pgfplots place the tick labels?

Comment: @AlfredoSánchezAlberca I guess you are asking because my labels where centered at the given coordinates, which doesn't fit anymore when the labels change. I have modified the code, the positioning should now coincide with where `pgfplots` puts the labels. This is probably not the way how `pgfplots` does it, but it should give the same result.

Comment: Thank again @gernot!
Now the labels of your nodes coincide with the ones that pgfplots puts via `xticklabels` and `yticklabels`, but if you change the width of the plot with  `width=3cm`, for instance, you have that the labels doesn't match again. 
I think pgfplots there must use a relative placement of tick labels.

Comment: @AlfredoSánchez I have added another solution that leaves the positioning of the labels to `pgfplots`.